# How to share instance between method with MapStruct

Tags: mapstruct

I need to convert an xml to jpa entity. I have used jaxb to get my DTO and use mapStruct to convert the dto into entity.
However, I need to extract some data from the data and set it as list on my entity. My mapper looks like this

```
Particulier toEntity(TParticulier particulier);
List<AttributMeta> toEntity(List<TAttributMeta> attributMetas);
default String extractMetaData(TAttributGufIdWithMeta value) {
List<TAttributMeta> attributMetas=value.getAttributMeta();   
???particulier.addAttributMetas(toEntity(attributMetas));??
return value.getValue().getGufid();
}
```

I don't know how to get access to my entity Particulier within extractMetaData method.

Answer (score 0):

In order to such mappings you need to use `@MappingTarget` combined with `@BeforeMapping` / `@AfterMapping`. For more info read [here](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#customizing-mappings-with-before-and-after) in the reference documentation.

In a nutshell you need your mapper or a used reference to have a method like:

```
@AfterMapping // It can also be @BeforeMapping
public void afterMapping(TParticulier source, @MappingTarget Particulier target) {
    //do what you need here
}
```